# Entity Framework + PostgreSql : very slow API performance on million rows

Tags: .net, postgresql, api, entity-framework, data-analysis

I am currently working on a project with millions rows. Doing it with Linq. I am making sure I am triggering data to model at the end.

The .NET API works well with small queries, but when it comes to bigger ones, it could take up to 2-3 seconds. Not that bad. But when I load 4-5 queries at same time, it's like there is a bottleneck somewhere. It would take 12-20 seconds for the server to respond.

Any idea why?

[image]

Basic .NET API with queries doing data statistic. Normally had no problems with SQL Server, wondering if it's Postgres. I have tried to use PgBouncer, Vacuum the DB, add work_mem, add index to table...

Nothing helps

Here are the query that LINQ generate, they all takes maximum 2.8 sec, some are faster :

```
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile AS m
WHERE m.received_at IS NOT NULL




SELECT avg(COALESCE(t.c, 0)::double precision)
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS empty
) AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*)::int AS c
    FROM smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile AS m
    WHERE m.received_at IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY m.survey_id
) AS t ON TRUE




SELECT avg(COALESCE(date_part('epoch', t.time_to_response) / 60.0, 0.0))
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS empty
) AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m.time_to_response
    FROM smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile AS m
    WHERE m.time_to_response IS NOT NULL
) AS t ON TRUE




SELECT m.date_hour, m.week_day, round(avg(date_part('epoch', m.time_to_response) / 60.0)::numeric, 2)
FROM smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile AS m
WHERE m.time_to_response IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.week_day, m.date_hour
ORDER BY m.week_day, m.date_hour




SELECT COALESCE(m.week_seniority::text, ''), round(CAST((count(*) FILTER (WHERE m.received_at IS NOT NULL)::int::double precision * 100.0) AS numeric) / count(*)::int::numeric, 2)
FROM smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile AS m
WHERE m.week_seniority > 0
GROUP BY m.week_seniority
ORDER BY m.week_seniority
```

Comment: _" I have tried to use PgBouncer, Vacuum the DB, add work_mem, add index to table..."_ - **show us the actual query SQL** that EF runs: you haven't posted any helpful details so far. Also share the `CREATE INDEX` statements that you ran.

Comment: the thing is, its ok when I run one query at a time. The problem comes when there is more at the same time.

Comment: [What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/postgresql/how-to-troubleshoot-and-fix-postgresql-performance-issues/)

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: It does not seem surprising that running 5 times more queries takes 5 times longer.  Can you explain why this surprises you?

Comment: EF should create short time lifespan connection, the queries are async and should not wait for one two finish to start an other. Its 5 different call to the api. You have api handling a lot more queries at same time, process time should not adds up...

Comment: what is the volume of your data? how many rows does the table smartboard.mvw_user_survey_and_profile has?

Comment: 10M rows and it will grow each days. Its a materialized view of many tables, and about 22 columns with varchar(100), numbers and date.